# How to generate the table in beamer using ShareLaTeX as shown in figure

Tags: tables, matrices

I'm trying to generate a table inside which numbers are to be inserted as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid[step=2cm] (6,8);
\foreach \X [count=\x] in {0,...,3} 
{\foreach \Y [count=\y] in {0,...,4}
 {
 \ifnum\Y=0
  \node[anchor=north west] (X-\X-\Y) at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\y,\x};
 \else
  \ifnum\X=0
   \node[anchor=south east] (X-\X-\Y) at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\y,\x};
  \else
   \node[anchor=south west] (X-\X-\Y) at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\y,\x};
  \fi
 \fi
 }
}
\path (X-3-2.east) -- (X-3-3.east) node[midway,right=2pt]{$m_y=5$};
\path (X-1-0.south) -- (X-2-0.south) node[midway,below=2pt]{$m_x=4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add m_x on the x-axis, m_y on the y-axis? Thank you.

Comment: @SaiKiranReddyMaryada I added these things. BTW, you have gotten an answer to one of your previous question, and you might want to consider accepting and perhaps upvoting it.