# Numbering in 2 Dimensional grid using beamer and dividing the slide into two halves as shown in figure

Tags: beamer, numbering, grids

[image]

Hello,

I'm trying to number the elements in the grid as follows. I'm wondering if I can get some help. Thank you.
I'm confused to write the logic.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%codification of the document
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\title[Module 8]{MODULE 8 \\ Data Matrix : Generation }
\author[aa]{by\\aa
}
% START add slide number
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
% END add slide number


\date

\begin{document}


%1
%Here begins the body of the document
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%13
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Re-numbered 2-D grid}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.4, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]

\draw (0,0) grid[step=2cm] (6,8);
\foreach \X [count=\x] in {0,...,3} 
{\foreach \Y [count=\y] in {0,...,4}
 {
 \ifnum\Y=0
  \node[anchor=north west] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\x};
 \else
  \ifnum\Y=1
    {
   \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr\x+4};
    }
 \else
  \ifnum\Y=2
    {
   \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr\x+8};
    }
 \else
  \ifnum\Y=3
   {
   \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr\x+12};
    }
  \else
  {
   \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr\x+16};
  }
  \fi
 \fi
 \fi
 \fi
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442559/how-to-generate-the-table-in-beamer-using-sharelatex-as-shown-in-figure?

Comment: I wrote the code using the above answer. But still unable to figure it out. Let me know my mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To divide the slide in two halves, simply place the two `tikzpicture`s next to each other.

Some other comments regarding your code:

- `\usepackage{utopia}` this package is obsolete
- You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- Please do not load the same package multiple time, e.g. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- Instead of this complicate construct

  ```
  % START add slide number
  \newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
  \let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
  \renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
   \oldmacro\hfill%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
  % END add slide number
  ```

  you can simply use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]`
- in your tikz code, you could save a lot of if-else conditions by using `\x+\Y*4`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
%\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%codification of the document
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\title[Module 8]{MODULE 8 \\ Data Matrix : Generation }
\author[aa]{by\texorpdfstring{\\}{}aa}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Re-numbered 2-D grid}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.4, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]

\draw (0,0) grid[step=2cm] (6,8);
\foreach \X [count=\x] in {0,...,3} 
{\foreach \Y [count=\y] in {0,...,4}
 {
 \ifnum\Y=0
  \node[anchor=north west] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\x};
 \else
   \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr\x+\Y*4};
 \fi
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.4, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]

\draw (0,0) grid[step=2cm] (6,8);
\foreach \X [count=\x] in {0,...,3} 
{\foreach \Y [count=\y] in {0,...,4}
 {
 \ifnum\Y=0
  \node[anchor=north west] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr(\x-1)*5+1};
 \else
  \node[anchor=south east] at (2*\X,2*\Y) {\number\numexpr(\x-1)*5+\Y+1};
 \fi
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]